# Cypress: nested custom commands

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm using Cypress 9.5.3 and Typescript 4.5.

Is there a way to create custom commands hierarchically? As a result I'd like to type (as an example):

```
cy.loginAs.admin();
```

Currently I can only write a command:

```
cy.loginAsAdmin();
```

Also support from VSC is important for me.

**EDIT 1**

I'd like to use those nested commands like this:

```
cy.loginAs.admin();
cy.loginAs.operator();
cy.loginAs.user();
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You could always write your custom command to have different flows and take in the role as a parameter. Something like `cy.loginAs('admin');` or `cy.loginAs('user');`

Comment: This is just example. I extended question.

Comment: You would reverse the order, since Cypress commands pass a "subject" down the chain (not up) - `cy.asAdmin().login()`. But your example is too trivial what would `admin()` do but return the string "admin"? Does it need to check context in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to add the role as a parameter to your custom command.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('loginAs', (role: string) => {
  switch (role) {
    case 'Admin':
      // code
    case 'Operator':
      // code
    case 'User':
      // code
    default:
      // code
  }
});

cy.loginAs('admin');
cy.loginAs('operator');
cy.loginAs('user');
```

If you knew you had a limited number of roles, you could create an enum.

```js
enum Roles {
  Admin,
  Operator,
  User
}

Cypress.Commands.add('loginAs', (role: Roles) => {
  //code 
})

cy.loginAs(Roles.Admin);
cy.loginAs(Roles.Operator);
cy.loginAs(Roles.User);
```

Using a `switch` statement is just a suggestion, but depending on how different the flows are, you may have more success with a different method.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add nested commands by extending the global "cy" object.

**From the Cypress Docs:**

> Public interface for the global "cy" object. If you want to add
> a custom property to this object, you should extend this interface.
> @see https://on.cypress.io/typescript#Types-for-custom-commands

[link to Cypress Docs](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/cli/types/cypress.d.ts#L5906)

**Example based on your question:**

```js
// cypress/support/loginAs.ts
function admin () {

}

function operator () {

}

export default {
  admin,
  operator,
}

// cypress/support/index.ts
import loginAs from './loginAs';

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface cy {
      loginAs: typeof loginAs 
   }
  }
}

cy.loginAs = loginAs;
```